# Weird C# bug when replacing a text string

Tags: c#, string, static

We have a registration-type system that sends a confirmation e-mail once completed. The system  had around 3000 registrations within a few minutes and we noticed a bug. If user A registers a few ms after user B has registered, user A will get user B's details via e-mail. We did manage to fix the issue and I narrowed it down to this piece of code that gets the e-mail template from the cache and just does a string replace on a place holder.

```
private string ProcessEmailBody(MyRegistrationModel registration)
{
    var content = CacheHelper.GetContent("REGISTRATIONEMAIL");

    if (content != null)
    {
        content.Text = context.Text.Replace("@@FULL_NAME@@", registration.FullName);

        return content.Text;
    }
    else return null;
}
```

The `CacheHelper.GetContent()` method is static and I fixed this "bug" by doing this:

```
private string ProcessEmailBody(MyRegistrationModel registration)
{
    var content = CacheHelper.GetContent("REGISTRATIONEMAIL");

    if (content != null)
    {
        string body = content.Text;
        body = body.Replace("@@FULL_NAME@@", registration.FullName);

        return body;
    }
    else return null;
}
```

And I can't figure out for the life of me why this has fixed the issue. Can anybody shed any light on this?

**EDIT**: Here's my GetContent() method (I know the signatures are different than above, I was being brief)

```
public static Content GetContent(string key, int partnerSiteId, int? version, IContentRepository contentRepository, out string cacheKey)
{
    cacheKey = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", key, partnerSiteId, version);

    var content = CacheManager.Get(cacheKey, () => contentRepository.GetContent(key, partnerSiteId, version), WebConfig.GetCacheDuration(CacheProfile.Short));

    return content;
}

private static DataCache _Cache = null; // DataCache is from AppFabric (Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching)

public static T Get<T>(string objectKey, Func<T> reloadItemExpresion, TimeSpan cacheDuration) where T : class
{
    if (_Cache == null)
    {
        if (reloadItemExpresion != null)
        {
            return reloadItemExpresion.Invoke();
        }

        return null;
    }

    object cachedObject = null;

    try
    {
        cachedObject = _Cache.Get(objectKey);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is FileNotFoundException)
        {
            _Cache.Remove(objectKey);
        }
    }

    if (cachedObject != null)
    {
        return cachedObject as T;
    }

    if (reloadItemExpresion != null && cacheDuration > TimeSpan.Zero)
    {
        T item = reloadItemExpresion.Invoke();

        if (item != null)
        {
            Insert(item, objectKey, cacheDuration);
        }

        return item;
    }

    return null;
}
```

`contentRepository.GetContent` just goes off to the database and fetches the actual content back.

Comment: Reveal the code of `CacheHelper.GetContent`… Most likely it provides instances *shared* among multiple threads, so you are creating a race condition when modifying `content.Text`.

Comment: There is not enough information; what is the actual type of `content`? How is the `GetContent` method implemented? Do you always hand out the same instance of `content`? Does this code run multi-threaded? In that case this might simply be a race condition and you need to ensure proper thread synchronization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first time through you replace the `"@@FULL_NAME@@"` tag in `context.Text` with the details of the first user. Once you do that, it never goes back to `"@@FULL_NAME@@"` again, so everybody gets that dude's details until your cache is reset. You should avoid modifying objects that you get from cache:

```
private string ProcessEmailBody(MyRegistrationModel registration) {
    var content = CacheHelper.GetContent("REGISTRATIONEMAIL");
    return content != null ? content.Replace("@@FULL_NAME@@", registration.FullName) : null;
}
```

Comment: @eth0 Nothing has changed, really: your code modifies a shared instance, which is returned to every request that calls `CacheHelper` within the short time interval defined through `WebConfig.GetCacheDuration(CacheProfile.Short)`, and then the cached value presumably gets reset. If you make cache duration longer, more users would see the content of the first user sent to them.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. I had my cache timeout set to 60 seconds but we never saw two registrations more than 6 seconds a part. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: @eth0 The reason for the 6 seconds vs. 60 seconds is hard to guess without seeing your configuration. Catching this situation in a debugger would give you more insight into what is really happening. The important thing to remember is that cached objects generally should not be modified, otherwise your mods will be visible to everybody. Treating cached instances as read-only is a good practice.

Comment: Whats the best way to treat cached objects as read-only? I can only think of marking objects properties as readonly but we use them elsewhere where they need be writeable...

Comment: @eth0 One way is to put a read-only interface on top of them: object's properties remain writable, but the properties of the interface that the object implements are read-only. For example, your `Content` could implement `IContent` with a read-only property `Text`. You would construct `Content` objects for the cache, but change the cache helper to return `IContent` objects back to you.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work, especially with our project size, heh. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `content` object is a shared object between everyone who accesses it. By using the first approach `content.Text = context.Text.Replace()` you are going to mutate the Text for everyone who is concurrently accessing it.

In your second approach you don't mutate the text within the shared object, thus everyone gets his own text concurrently. To avoid this problem in the future you should think about making your `content.Text` property read-only to the consumers (by allowing to set the text only in the constructor or only giving out interfaces with read-only access). Thus avoiding this bug even at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without knowing how your CacheHelper method works, or what type `content` is. But it seems that instead of returning a string, it returns a Content object of some sort, by reference. So that if two threads are running at once, both might be using the same Content object returned by the CacheHelper.

Assuming the CacheHelper is in charge of not creating a brand new Content template every time you call it, your original code is buggy in the sense that every Replace call changes the TEMPLATE, rather than the string derived from it.

I'm guessing this code will also work:

```
string body = content.Text.Replace("@@FULL_NAME@@", registration.FullName);
return body;
```

The important bit isn't reading the content's Text into a local variable, it's not replacing the content's Text property, which is apparently shared.